# Can't read xml data into a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I need to read an xml doc into a web page. I am using ajax but am having problems reading the data. Here is my code:

```
function getXML() {
    var newURL = "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext&v=5Ovh9KJ25ow&lang=en";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: newURL,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: xmlParser
        });
    });

    function xmlParser(xml) {
        $(xml).find("text").each(function() {
            alert('hi');
            $("#caption").append('<div>' + $(this).find("text").text() + '</div>');
        });
    }
}
```

In the body of the webpage I have `<div id="caption"></div>`.
If you view that URL https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?&v=5Ovh9KJ25ow&lang=en you will see that it is an xml doc with "text" nodes. These nodes also include a "start" attribute that I will need as well. I put a javascript alert('hi') in just to see if it was running and I get "hi" 19 times as expected for the 19 text nodes, but nothing gets written to my div. Once I get the data to show up, how do I access the "start" attribute data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `$(this).find("text").text()` instead of `$(this).text()`.

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
  $(xml).find("text").each(function() {
    $("#caption").append('<div>' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
  });
}
```

```js
function xmlParser(xml) {
  $(xml).find("text").each(function() {
    $("#caption").append(
      '<li>' +
        '<p>Text: ' + $(this).text() + '</p>' +
        '<p>Start (jQuery way): ' + $(this).attr('start') + '</p>' + 
        '<p>Start (JavaScript way): ' + this.getAttribute('start') + '</p>' + 
      '</li>'
    );
  });
}

xmlParser(`<transcript>
<text start="0.01" dur="4.04">{music}</text>
<text start="4.07" dur="4.04">
What is the One Button Studio? The One Button Studio is simply
</text>
<text start="8.13" dur="4">
a standard video recording studio where we&#39;ve removed the technology from
</text>
<text start="12.15" dur="4.01">
the floor and mounted it to the ceiling and we&#39;ve also automated the space.
</text>
<text start="16.18" dur="4">
We did this to enhance the user experience. You no longer need to know how to work
</text>
<text start="20.2" dur="4.08">
lights, camera, or audio to create a good quality video.
</text>
<text start="24.3" dur="4.09">
To work it, we just bring a thumb drive and we simply plug it into the hub here.
</text>
<text start="28.41" dur="4.12">
And within a few seconds, we&#39;re gonna see ourselves on the
</text>
<text start="32.55" dur="4.08">
monitor and the lights will come on, and we&#39;re ready to go. To start, we
</text>
<text start="36.65" dur="4.01">
simply press the button. We get a five second countdown. If we so choose,
</text>
<text start="40.68" dur="4.08">
we can use a projector to project an image or we can use the green screen on the ceiling to
</text>
<text start="44.78" dur="4.02">
shoot a standard green screen video. And once we&#39;ve created our video,
</text>
<text start="48.82" dur="4.06">
we just simply press the button again. It will save that video
</text>
<text start="52.9" dur="4.02">
to a QuickTime formatted file right to the thumb drive. And when it&#39;s finished,
</text>
<text start="56.94" dur="4.03">
we can just take that thumb drive out, everything will turn off, and we&#39;re ready to go.
</text>
<text start="60.99" dur="4">{music}</text>
<text start="65.01" dur="4.04"></text>
<text start="69.07" dur="4.01"></text>
<text start="73.1" dur="2.668"></text>
</transcript>`)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="caption"></ul>
```

Comment: That was it exactly. Thanks so much. Is there a way to access the start attribute too? I would like to list those as well as the text.

Comment: I tried .childNodes[0] and .getAttribute("start") after text() and also after .find("text") on the line before it but that didn't work.

Comment: @user3499381 I've updated the answer to include the `start` attribute using both the `jQuery` and `JavaScript` way.  If this is helpful, please mark this answer as correct.  Also, you should mark the helpful answers to your previous questions as correct as well. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user3499381 I think it's also worth pointing out that using `.getAttribute("start") after text()` is the same mistake as using `$(this).find("text").text()`.  You need to understand what you have after every chained method.  For example, after `$(this).text()`, you just have a string equal to the innerText of the Dom Element referenced by `this`.  You can't use `.getAttribute()` or `.attr()` on a string.  Those are methods that can be used on a Dom Element.

Comment: @user3499381 If you aren't sure what you are working with, just `console.log` the value to see.  If you `console.log($(this))`, you'll see a Dom Element.  If you `console.log($(this).text())`, you'll see a string.